# Logic by which we can loop over an object when we aren't certain that whether it will be a single object or an array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON output that can contain the following types of data:

1. An array of objects

   ```
   var data = {
               "EARNINGS": [
                      {
                        "PAYMENT": "1923.08",
                        "REPORTING_NAME": "Regular Salary",
                        "CATEGORY_NAME": "Standard Earnings"
                      },
                      {
                        "PAYMENT": "0",
                        "REPORTING_NAME": "Spot Bonus",
                        "CATEGORY_NAME": "Supplemental Earnings"
                      }
                    ]
   }
   ```
2. An object:

   ```
     var data = {
          "EARNINGS": 
                  {
                    "PAYMENT": "1923.08",
                    "REPORTING_NAME": "Regular Salary",
                    "RUN": "1923.08",
                   }
              };
   ```

How to loop through the "EARNINGS" object? as for the case of array of objects I'm able to do so but in the case of single object I have to check whether it's an array or not.

Comment: Can't you change the data structure so that you always have an array? `earnings` is plural after all.

Comment: Actually, the response is nested and there are other tags as well for which I would have to change the data structure or check whether it's an array or object and then proceed with my processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can Check it by `Array.isArray(data)`;  it will return true or false.

```js
var data_single = {
  "EARNINGS": {
    "PAYMENT": "1923.08",
    "REPORTING_NAME": "Regular Salary",
    "CATEGORY_NAME": "Standard Earnings",
  }
};

var data_arr = {
  "EARNINGS": [
  {
    "PAYMENT": "1923.08",
    "REPORTING_NAME": "Regular Salary",
    "RUN": "1923.08",
  },
  {
    "PAYMENT": "0",
    "REPORTING_NAME": "Spot Bonus",
    "CATEGORY_NAME": "Supplemental Earnings"
  }
  ]
};

console.log(Array.isArray(data_single['EARNINGS']));
console.log(Array.isArray(data_arr['EARNINGS']));
```